# Broken markdown parsing with non-url encoded links

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

**Here's the source**

```
    $(function(){

    }); 

is [jQuery][1] (a Javascript library) shorthand for:

    $(document).ready(function(){

    });

It is what you use to do with `` but more sophisticated. You can 
get a fuller explanation [here][2].

  [1]: http://www.jquery.com
  [2]: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()
```

**Here's the output**

```
$(function(){

});
```

is [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (a Javascript library) shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

It is what you use to do with `<body onload="xxx">` but more sophisticated. You can 
get a fuller explanation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/issues/detail?id=27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sanitizer doesn't like the non-encoded $ remaining in the URL. I added it to the list of characters encoded in `EncodeProblemUrlChars()`

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=110

Note that the javascript preview in `showdown.js` can't deal with the parens in the link, but the server-side version can.